# ionic installation showing issues in command line

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i am try to install ionic but it showing following error in cmd line.Please find log in command line.

```
> C:\Users\mohan>npm install -g ionic

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/domhandler/-/domhandler-2.3.0.t
gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stre
am-1.1.13.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/entities/-/entities-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/domelementtype/-/domelementtype
-1.3.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.2.11.
tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.1.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom/-/xmldom-0.1.19.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-package-data/-/normal
ize-package-data-2.3.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"4.1.1","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bund
led package wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\phonegap-build\node_modules\qrcode-terminal requires colors@'*'
but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will loa
d
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phoneg
ap\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
ionic@1.6.5 C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
├── proxy-middleware@0.7.0
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── connect-livereload@0.5.2
├── progress@1.1.7
├── open@0.0.5
├── colors@0.6.2
├── q@1.0.1
├── async@0.9.2
├── crc@3.2.1
├── ncp@0.4.2
├── semver@4.3.6
├── shelljs@0.2.6
├── cross-spawn@0.2.3 (lru-cache@2.7.0)
├── cli-table@0.3.1 (colors@1.0.3)
├── form-data@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11, combined-stream@0.0.7)
├── xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1, xmlbuilder@3.1.0)
├── npm@2.1.3
├── event-stream@3.0.20 (pause-stream@0.0.11, from@0.1.3, duplexer@0.1.1, stream
-combiner@0.0.4, split@0.2.10, through@2.3.8, map-stream@0.0.6)
├── finalhandler@0.2.0 (escape-html@1.0.1, debug@2.0.0)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── connect@3.1.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, debug@1.0.4, finalhandler@
0.1.0)
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, qs@0.5.6, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0
.3)
├── serve-static@1.7.1 (escape-html@1.0.1, utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, se
nd@0.10.1)
├── request@2.51.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, caseless@0.8.0, tunnel
-agent@0.4.1, oauth-sign@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, m
ime-types@1.0.2, qs@2.3.3, node-uuid@1.4.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, tough-cookie@
2.0.0, form-data@0.2.0, hawk@1.1.1, bl@0.9.4, http-signature@0.10.1)
├── opbeat-ionic@1.1.3 (console-log-level@1.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, stac
kman@0.2.3, after-all@2.0.2)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, lodash@2.4.2, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.
6, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6, through2@0.6.5, mkdirp@0.5.1)
├── prompt@0.2.12 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.7, winston@0.6.2,
utile@0.2.1)
├── cheerio@0.19.0 (entities@1.1.1, lodash@3.10.1, dom-serializer@0.1.0, css-sel
ect@1.0.0, htmlparser2@3.8.3)
├── gulp@3.8.8 (pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, interpret@0.3.10, deprecated@0.0.1, a
rchy@0
.0.2, minimist@1.2.0, semver@3.0.1, tildify@1.1.1, chalk@0.5.1, liftoff@0.12.1,
orchestrator@0.3.7, gulp-util@3.0.6)
├── unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, pullstream@0.4.1, m
atch-stream@0.0.2, binary@0.3.0, fstream@0.1.31)
└── ionic-app-lib@0.3.9 (archiver@0.5.2, vinyl-fs@1.0.0, ionic-cordova-lib@5.1.7
)
```

And given ionic start project
it shows nothing. Please help me to solve these.

*In command prompt i am given **ionic** it not showing anything please check image.*

How to know the issues.
[image]

Comment: try to fire npm command in cmd and tell what's happen

Comment: iam gettinf these: C:\Users\mohan>npm
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:

Comment: where <command> is one of:access, add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c,cache, completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag,dist-tags, docs, edit, explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get,help, help-search, home, i, info, init, install, issues, la,  link, list, ll, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix, prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm, root, run-script, s, se, search, set,  show, shrinkwrap, star, stars, start, stop, t, tag, team,test, tst, un, uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up,update, upgrade, v, verison,  view, whoami

Comment: npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\mohan\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@2.14.4 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

C:\Users\mohan>